# separate library paths in folder structure view

Tags: foobar2000

i want to move to foobar since it has some cool features.

however one thing that annoys me and i wonder how to fix this:

i have an external hard drive with the complete library and on internal disk also some stuff (may be the same since i cpied the stuff i want to hear to laptop)

if i add both, the external and the internal musik directories then foobar mixes the contents of the directories together.

example:

drive content:

```
e:\Music\InterpretA\Album1
e:\Music\InterpretA\Album2
e:\Music\InterpretA\Album3
e:\Music\InterpretB\Album1

c:\Music\InterpretA\Album1
c:\Music\InterpretB\Album1
```

i added `e:\music` and `c:\music` to library

and in folder strucutre view foobar mixes them up to:

```
+- InterpretA
|  +- Album1
|  +- Album1
|  +- Album2
|  +- Album3
+- InterpretB
   +- Album1
   +- Album1
```

I would prefer something like:

```
 +-"e:\Music\"
 |  +- InterpretA
 |  |  +- Album1
 |  |  +- Album2
 |  |  +- Album3
 |  +- InterpretB
 |     +- Album1
 +-"c:\Music\" 
    +- InterpretA
    |  +- Album1
    +- InterpretB
       +- Album1
```

is there any way to achive that?

Comment: Which GUI do you use: Default UI or Columns UI?

Answer (score 4):

You can use symbolic links for that. Create some folder, say "C:\Program Files (x86)\foobar2000\library", go to it in Windows cmd.exe, use Windows built-in "mklink" command line to create links to your folders like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\foobar2000\library>mklink /D "MUSIC" "Q:\MUSIC"
symbolic link created for MUSIC > Q:\MUSIC
```

Then add your "library" folder to foobar and set the album view to "by folder structure". Foobar doesn't seem to follow regular Windows shortcuts, but soft links work.

Answer (score 1):

This applies to the default UI: at the bottom of the Album List panel, go to the drop-down list for "View." There's an option for "Folder structure." This will organize your files the way you want.

[image]

Comment: i was already talking about the behaviour of the "folder structure" view